# Magento 2: How to remove js included with requirejs-config.js

Tags: magento2

Is it possible to How to remove the js file that was included using requirejs-config.js

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible. Configure requirejs with:

```
var config = {
    paths: {
        nameOf: '//url/to/file/without/js/extension'
    }
}
```

next, you can use it into magento components, widgets and so on as:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'nameOf',
], function ($, nameOfRef) {
}
```

It's working for me.